# How can I do Unstack of two columns like the one in Minitab

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have the following data in a Pandas data frame:

| Cavity | Dimension |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.45 |
| 1 | 1.47 |
| 1 | 1.46 |
| 1 | 1.45 |
| 1 | 1.43 |
| 2 | 1.40 |
| 2 | 1.39 |
| 2 | 1.41 |
| 2 | 1.40 |
| 2 | 1.42 |
| 3 | 1.51 |
| 3 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 1.49 |
| 3 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 1.52 |

how can I reshape the data to the following format in pandas?

| Cavity 1 | Cavity 2 | Cavity 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.45 | 1.40 | 1.51 |
| 1.47 | 1.39 | 1.50 |
| 1.46 | 1.41 | 1.49 |
| 1.45 | 1.40 | 1.50 |
| 1.43 | 1.42 | 1.52 |

is there any way to do this reshape (melt backwards)?

thanks for your help!!

Comment: Use `df = df.assign(g = df.groupby('Cavity').cumcount()).pivot(index='g', columns='Cavity', values='Dimension').add_prefix('Cavity ')`